# LoadLibrary failure: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in R

Tags: c++, c, r

I have a C code which is loaded through R for my project. Using dyn.load, I was able to load the C code in Windows 64 bit machine and Linux server. However, I am getting the following error when I try to load .dll in Windows 32bit machine.

[R error while using dyn.load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t68fR.png)

I tried using the whole path, running the dyn.load command from working directory but none of them worked. 
My R version:
[R version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWEYC.png)

Also, I have edited the system variables and below you can find the system variables.

```
`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\Roxio Central36;
C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;
C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin;
C:\Rtools\bin;
C:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin;
C:\Rtools\mingw_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.9.3;
C:\Users\******\Documents\R\R-3.3.2\library\Rcpp`
```

The existing solutions for this type of problem did not help me.

It would be great if someone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: *"The existing solutions for this type of problem did not help me."* - We ain't mind readers. We don't know which solutions you have tried that apparently didn't help. Anyway, you are loading a 64-bit module into a 32-bit process. This isn't going to end well. You'll have to get a hold of a 32-bit module.

Answer (score 4):

My computer was missing 64 bit java, all I had to do was install it:

- Go [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)
- Click on 'Windows Offline (64-bit)' to download 64 bit java
- Click on the downloaded file and follow the installation instructions
- Close RStudio then reopen RStudio
- Everything worked!

Comment: Thanks that worked when other advice didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Such errors often refer to architecture mismatch, apparently when one tries to load a x86-64 module on a x86 machine. Please, make sure that on the x86 machine you're loading a .dll compiled specifically for the x86 architecture.